# PHP simple date question

Tags: php, datetime, date

### Function

```
echo date( "m/d/Y h:i a", "10/22/2009 12:32 am" );
```

### Output

```
12/31/1969 07:00 pm
```

Why is my output not giving me the correct date, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo date( "m/d/Y h:i a", strtotime("10/22/2009 12:32 am" ));
```

Answer (score 3):

The second argument should be a timestamp, not a date string.

Comment: Try echo date( "m/d/Y h:i a", strtotime("10/22/2009 12:32 am") );

Answer (score 1):

How you can read in the [PHP Documentation for the date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) the second parameter must be an unix timestamp. You can use the [mktime Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to convert your date into a timestamp.